# Defining projection surface height in proj4 string

Tags: gdal, proj4js

I'm using proj4 in an actual project, which needs accurate projection calculation. To realize accurate projection, it defines a projection surface height, which is calculated from the average altitude of the working zone. It is like, for example:
If the projection surface height is 100m, and I'm using WGS84 datum, I have to add 100m to an of the datum and maintain the eccentricity(e) of the datum, which will make the b become (a+100)(1-f), where f=1/298.257222101

Now my working solution is directly using the a and b computed as mentioned above in the string, like

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=30 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6378237.0 +b=6356852 +units=m +no_defs
```

where `+a=6378237.0` means the a of WGS84(6378137.0) plus 100m, `+b=6356852` means 6378237.0*(1-1/298.257222101), f is the oblateness of WGS84 datum.

Now I'm wondering is there any parameter in the proj4 string that can let me directly specify the projection surface height directly, instead of manually giving a and b? like `+proj_surface_height=100m`?